# OpenCV C++ how to make dwell click?

Tags: c++, opencv, clickable

I'm trying to build a program using opencv library.
I intend to make a laser pointer mouse.

so far, the program can detect laser point and move the cursor location that location in realtime.

now i want to give the program an ability to perform click and if possible a double click.

the only idea I have, is to do this by playing with the coordinate value for certain frame and subtract current frame coordinate with last frame coordinate.

my problem is...I dont know how implement it in code

should I use array to store the coordinate?? or any other solution i could use??

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

A click could be represented by the laser pointer disappearing and appearing near the same spot, and only if this happens within 1 second.

You could store the coordinates of the last frames in a [`std::vector`](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm) of [`CvPoint`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_basic_structures.html#cvpoint) and do a simple search in this vector when the laser pointer appears again. The last 30 coordinates or so should be stored, so you will always have the coordinates of that last 1 second of recording (at 30fps).

The double click is a small enhancement of the single click. For simplicity purposes, the double click could seen as 2 single clicks being detected within 2 seconds.